# How to wait for an asynchronous AudioTrack.write to finish?

Tags: android, asynchronous, audiotrack

I'd like to play back audio that is synthesized at 1/50 s increments. With the asynchronous streaming interface of [`AudioTrack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) my plan is to basically do the following:

```
while (!done)
{
  frame = synthesize();
  audio.waitForWrite(); // XXX
  audio.write(frame, 0, frameSize, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
}
audio.waitForWrite(); // XXX
```

However, there is no `waitForWrite` or similar method on `AudioTrack` that I could use here; and if I just do a non-blocking write, the second frame will replace the first one in the middle, i.e. let's say synthesis of a 20ms frame takes 5 ms, then the first frame will play for 5ms and then get replaced by the second one after 5ms and so on, which is clearly not what I want.

On the other hand, if I use blocking writes, then I can't synthesize the next frame while the previous one is already playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand streaming mode.  Write doesn't take the amount of time it takes to play it.  Write copies it to another buffer.  In blocking mode, it will wait until the entire buffer is copied, but not until its played.  In non-blocking mode, it will copy as much as it can right now and return immediately.  There is no need to wait for it to be played in either mode, and no reason to.

Comment: It's not true to say there's no reason to. For example I want to play a sound for as long as that sound lasts and then wait 1 second before playing the next sound.

Comment: @mjaggard Read the question again.  He's talking about writing a track, not playing a track.  Completely separate operations.  Write is for writing the data to storage, it has nothing to do with playing a sound.

Comment: He specifically said he's in streaming mode so is definitely playing the sound. From the javadoc: "Writes the audio data to the audio sink for playback (streaming mode)"

Comment: @mjaggard That still wouldn't be how you do it.  You'd wait on the player, not the streaming writer.  Because the writer writes data asynchronously and at a much faster rate, allowing you to asynchronously ready the next batch of data.  If you wanted to know when its played, you wait on the playing end.  Putting that into the writing API would be counterproductive.  Thats why the function is called write() and not play().  Even if you use the blocking mode it wouldn't wait for the play to be finished, just for the write.  You don't use a producer api to time a consumer.

Comment: @mjaggard In addition, write finishing doesn't mean the data has been played.  It means it's been written.  That could mean it's been played.  Or it could have been written into the producer's memory.  Or sent over a socket (or shared memory, or other communication method) to another process.   All of these are typical producer/consumer  communication methods.  Write returning, even in a blocking context, only means that the consumer has the data, it does not mean that the consumer has used the data (in this case, it doesn't know if its been played).

Comment: OK. So for the OP the issue they need to solve is how to not write data too fast on the producer end in streaming mode - does blocking help or will it just fill up or replace a buffer somewhere or does he need to sleep between synthesis?